# Call codeigniter backend api from angular 2

Tags: angular, api, codeigniter

I am using angular 2 on front end and codeigniter in back end. codeigniter install in api folder which is subdirectory of angular 2 project. when i am calling my codeigniter api, by default angular 2 index page loading .How i can solve this issue ??

Comment: Sorry I can't understand your question, do you build a web service?

Comment: Why is your backend code a sub-directory of your frontend?? That makes no sense and exposes your backend API code to every people accessing your frontend

Comment: @GilangPratama i'm creating a admin panel using angular 2 and codeigniter but both are in same folder whenever i'm calling ci api, it redirect to angular 2 index page .

Comment: Do you have a server as Apache installed on your VPS? If so, you could try to define reverse proxies in order to redirect some of your backend requests to point to codeigniter process.